# get multiple reports in one report with Active Reports

Tags: activereports

How can I get Multiple reports (with deferent query) in one report using data dynamic active reports

Answer (score 8):

You can also create multiple reports, call Run() on each and then merge them together using ActiveReport.Document.Pages. Nice way to keep logic completely separated and merge documents together.

something like:

```
ActiveReport report1 = new ActiveReport();
ActiveReport report2 = new ActiveReport();
report1.Run();    
report2.Run();
report.Document.Pages.AddRange(report2.Document.Pages);
//do your exporting as normal
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than LordHits above. Thanks for the quick easy reference!

Comment: This doesn't appear to be an option with Page Reports, as the Document object doesn't have a pages collection in that case.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use one to many SubReports embedded in the main report.

Comment: LordHits is right. There is a detailed walkthrough showing how to use a subreport in ActiveReports at the following link: http://www.datadynamics.com/Help/ActiveReports6/ActiveReports6_start.html?arHOWEmbedSubreportsInAReport.html

Answer (score 1):

@Mehdi,

The solution provided by karnqu is better since merging not only saves memory but also avoids making use of multiple subreport controls on the main report which might be more time consuming when it comes to designing of reports. You may want to check this [blog article](https://rishblogs.wordpress.com/2011/09/05/how-to-merge-reports-with-activereports/) which provides information on report merging and a working example.

Thanks,
Sankalp